# BeautifulSoup and XML parsing

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am struggling with the use of BS. I have a TEI-XML file and I would like to capture only the content of `<p>`  and `<said>` tags.

So given this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
...

<body>
               ...
               <p n="10">**I think a quarter of an hour had elapsed** , when I rose to depart , and then , to my surprise , I noticed the half-franc still on the table , but the sous piece was gone .</p>
               <p n="11">
                  **I beckoned to a waiter , and said :
                  <said who="#the_English">“ One of you came to me a little while ago demanding payment . I think he was somewhat hasty in pressing for it ; however , I set the money down , and the fellow has taken the tip , and has neglected the charge for the coffee .** ”</said>
               </p>
...
</TEI>
```

this is the output I would like to have in CONLL Format  capturing the  tag:

```
I 0
think 0
a 0
quarter 0
of 0
...
...
...
...
and 0
said 0
: 0
“ B-said
One I-said
of I-said
you I-said
came I-said
to I-said
...
...
```

I have tried with this code:

```
 Import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
content = []
# Read the XML file
with open("speakers/ABookofGhostsbySSabineBaringGould36638.xml", "r") as file:
    # Read each line in the file, readlines() returns a list of lines
    content = file.readlines()
    # Combine the lines in the list into a string
    content = "".join(content)
    bs_content = bs(content, "lxml")

all_txt=[]
for result in bs_content.findAll("p"):
    said=result.find('said')
    if said ==None:
        conll=[f"{token}'\t'0" for token in result.get_text().split()]
        all_txt.append(conll)
    else:
        ...
```

I am ok at managing the `<p>` without the `<said>` tag (the first part of the `if` block) but when I got a line like this:

```
<p n="11">
                  I beckoned to a waiter , and said :
                  <said who="#the_English">“ One of you came to me a little while ago demanding payment . I think he was somewhat hasty in pressing for it ; however , I set the money down , and the fellow has taken the tip , and has neglected the charge for the coffee . ”</said>
               </p>
```

I'm struggling with how to use BeautifulSoup to get the desired output (the second part of the `if` block, the `else`part).

Can you help me out in creating the python code with BeautifulSoup?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some code you have already written - How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way

```
     Import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
content = []
# Read the XML file
with open("speakers/ABookofGhostsbySSabineBaringGould36638.xml", "r") as file:
    # Read each line in the file, readlines() returns a list of lines
    content = file.readlines()
    # Combine the lines in the list into a string
    content = "".join(content)
    bs_content = bs(content, "lxml")

all_txt=[]
all_txt.append('sentenceID,word,tag')
counter=1
for result in bs_content.findAll("p"):
    said=result.find('said')
    if said ==None:
        for token in result.get_text().split():
            all_txt.append(f"{counter},{token.replace(',','')},0")
    else:
        said_list=list(said.strings)
        for each_result in result.strings:
                #print('THIS IS SENT '+each_result)
                if each_result not in said_list :
                    for token_result in each_result.split():
                        all_txt.append(f'{counter},{token_result.replace(",","")},0')
                else:
                    for each_said in said_list:
                        first=True
                        for token_said in each_said.split():
                            if first == True:
                                first=False
                                all_txt.append(f'{counter},{token_said.replace(",","")},B-said')
                            else:
                                all_txt.append(f'{counter},{token_said.replace(",","")},I-said')
    counter=counter+1
with open('your_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    for item in all_txt:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

I do not know if it is the best solution but it works.